# getting error problem running iptables when checking ufw status

Tags: 18.04, server, iptables, ufw

when I check ufw status on ubuntu I get the following error.

```
 ufw status
[sudo] password for rock: 
ERROR: problem running iptables: iptables v1.6.1: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

what should I do to fix it ?

Comment: What is the output of `uname -sr`?

Comment: Linux 4.4.154-95-rockchip-gd2ab1f26e1b3
from here https://wiki.radxa.com/Rockpi4/downloads

Comment: Looks like it might be due for a kernel upgrade, the latest release of iptables is 1.8.4 but my ubuntu machine also shows 1.6.1 and I'm fully up to date. If you do `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt full-upgrade` does that kick off a kernel update?

Comment: tried `sudo apt full-upgrade` and got `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.` then tried `sudo ufw status` and got same error

Comment: hmm, looking like a kernel issue, might have better luck with this question over on their forums, just a thought, sorry I can't help you fix it.

Comment: Is this a hosted computer? VM?

Comment: hosted on a computer. rock pi 4G single board computer

Comment: do you get any output for `sudo iptables -v -x -n -L`?

Comment: @DougSmythies : `$ sudo iptables -v -x -n -L
iptables v1.6.1: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.`

Comment: does [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/743678/cant-initialize-iptables-table-filter-table-does-not-exist-do-you-need-to-i) help?

Comment: @DougSmythies that wont , rpi-update is for raspbian OS on raspberry pi

Comment: I got this message in a chroot mode on linux rootfs installed on android.