# Nginx configuration failure: iptables table does not exist

Tags: iptables, nginx, ufw

I tried to configure nginx on my Ubuntu system. During this process, I executed the command `sudo ufw allow 'Nginx HTTP` and I got an error:

```
WARN: initcaps
[Errno 2] iptables v1.8.7 (legacy): can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.

Skipping adding existing rule
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't initialize iptables table \`filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/743678/cant-initialize-iptables-table-filter-table-does-not-exist-do-you-need-to-i)